# Finding annihilator matrix on the left for an other matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a matrix $A$ which is $m \times n$. I want to find matrix $F$ which annihilates the matrix $A$ on the left, i.e $F\cdot A = 0$. The book suggests that this can be done if the matrix $F$'s kernel is in the range of matrix $A$. How Can we find an annihilator matrix for another matrix on left? Any numerical example for a simple matrix $A$.

Comment: It is precisely the opposite: $FA = 0$ holds if and only if the range of $A$ is in the kernel of $F$

Comment: Do you know how to find the basis of the kernel of a matrix? If so, you can construct $F$ using a basis for the kernel of $A^\top$.

Comment: Also, presumably there is more to the definition of an "annihilator matrix" than $FA = 0$. For example, why doesn't $F = 0$ count as an annihilator matrix?

Comment: Do you know how to find a matrix $G$ which annihilates a given matrix $B$ on the right? If so, note that $FA=0$ is the same as $A^tF^t=0$, solve for $F^t$, and then transpose.

Comment: Are you still here, Math?

Answer (score 1):

According to comments and suggestions to the question. The matrix F can be found [using matlab] as
$$ F = transpose(null(transpose(A))) $$